# Dated Exchange Rates Question

Tags: multi-currency

What will happen if an Opportunity that was closed using the previous dated exchange rate got edited in the future? Will it use the current dated exchange rate or it will still use the original one?

Where can I find more information about Dated Exchange Rate aside from this one: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=administration_about_advanced_currency_management.htm&language=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out! It will get the current exchange rate if the closed date will be edited.